# Update no componente criado com o composite não funciona

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-5.2, componentes

Pessoal criei um componente usando o composite

```
<composite:implementation>

    <p:dataTable  id="#{cc.attrs.id}" 
      </dataTable>

    </composite:implementation>
```

Porém quando eu chamo ele no meu código ele funciona normal mas na hora que do update usando o primefaces ele não atualiza, alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Pode compartilhar a forma como está chamando o update deste componente ?

Comment: posso sim cara, to chamando assim
<dsm:dataTable id="table">
..... 
</dsm:dataTable>

<p:commandButton action="#{bean.pesquisar}" update="table"/>



se eu chamar o componente do datatable do primefaces normal funciona mas no que eu criei não funciona